# Transform a WS call to an Enumerator of whatever

Tags: playframework-2.1

Is there a clean way to transform an HTTP GET call (with WS API) that will stream (maybe forever) JsObjects into an Enumerator[JsObject].

Of course this enumerator has to be well wired with WS API, meaning if the Iteratee tells the enumerator to stop sending chunks, the enumerator will end the WS call and if the WS is done, the enumerator has to tell its iteratee that he is done.

I found some ugly solutions, but nothing really fit my needs.

It can be something like (pseudo code):

---

The stream service part :

```
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import play.api.libs.iteratee.{Enumeratee, Enumerator}
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise
import scala.util.Random
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import java.util.UUID

case class Data(id: String, payload: String)

object Application extends Controller {

  implicit val dataFmt = Json.format[Data]

  def stream = Action {
    val datas: Enumerator[Data] = Enumerator.generateM[Data] {
      Promise.timeout(
        Some(Data(UUID.randomUUID().toString, "Hello World")), Random.nextInt(500)
      )
    }
    Ok.chunked(datas.through(Enumeratee.map[Data](dataFmt.writes(_))))
  }
}
```

---

And the client/enumerator part :

```
val enumerator = WS.url("http://host:port/api/stream.json")
  .getStream() // here returns an Enumerator[Array[Byte]] for response chunks
  .through(Enumeratee.map[Array[Byte]](Json.parse(_)))
```

Comment: My attempt to provide such feature :
https://gist.github.com/mathieuancelin/6294116